# Is there a way to see what is using WCF named pipes?

Tags: wcf

## Preface

My knowledge of WCF, and named pipes is **less than zero**. This is a question I am asking out of necessity, not desire. I'm trying to troubleshoot something.

## Question

Is there any kind of tool, program, or place in Windows to see **everything** that is using WCF Named Pipes, and their origins, so that I can find out what is blocking my tool from working? More details below.

## Problem

I use a programming plugin called `JustCode` from `Telerik`. It is not working for me on my new computer, so I have been struggling to find out why. I have been in contact with Telerik technical support and review of the log files suggests that the problem is that **something** on my computer is *incorrectly using* `WCF Named Pipes`.

Attempts to further diagnose this led to me completely wiping the computer clean (secure 0 overwrite of the entire hard drive) and reinstalling Windows (`8.1 Professional x64)` from scratch **30 times**, installing **nothing** except the chipset INF driver, then *Visual Studio 2013 Professional with Update 3*, then *JustCode* - in that exact order. **No Windows Updates**, and no other drivers.

22 of 30 installs, JustCode did not work correctly. However 8 times it *did* work fine. These are extremely bizarre results and very confusing to me.

I have attempted this same test on 2 other machines, each with identical hardware *except* the motherboard and processor. My system uses a Haswell i7 (`AsRock Z87 Extreme 9/ac` motherboard), the other two machines used an IvyBridge i7 CPU and compatible motherboards (`ASUS Maximus IV Extreme`, `Gigabyte GA-X79-UP4`)

Here are my results;

- AsRock

22 out of 30 failed

- ASUS

16 out of 30 failed

- GIGABYTE

3 out of 30 failed

I realize that correlation does not directly mean causation, but it is the only lead I have so far.

As a temporary fix, I can run Visual Studio as Administrator and the tool works. But I'd like to avoid having to do that every time for a number of various reasons.

So there it is; With so little installed, I have to conclude there is some native behavior on some piece of hardware that is doing this. Having 0 knowledge of WCF or 'named pipes', I need to try and find a way to look at them and see which part is doing it.

Comment: What are the symptoms of the plug-in _not working_ vs _working_?

Comment: Well, when it works, it gives various improvements to intellisense, a better unit test runner, code refactoring, etc. These are not showing up when it fails to work. It is kind of like Resharper.

Comment: Ok. You might get some useful information if you run the dysfunctional IDE under [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I hope it is okay if I leave this question up for others to pitch in, though.

Comment: Sure. Also check the WCF performance counters in PerfMon - I am not using WCF ATM, but I seem to recall that each endpoint was listed out with certain information, possibly (part of) the pipe name among them.